# Will I be restricted to enter some countries if I am potential target for the terrorists?

Tags: international

**e.g.** killed ISIS member publicly, humiliated them and posted online

ISIS then angry and most likely would target me, can I still visit other countries as per normal? Will there be any laws to restrict me?

*Note: The example is baseless.*

Comment: `Note: The example is baseless.` is exactly what I would say in that situation.

Comment: Change the example to: _Offend some members of a religion to the point they attacked our offices_ (which is what happened to Charlie Hebdo). I don't think their employees were restricted in their travels anymore than other French citizens were, though if you _murder_ someone and you travel to another country the authorities there may have something to say about _that_.

Comment: I don't see how this is a political question, rather it's just a technical one about customs. Also the answer would be different for most of the <country of origin, destination country> pairs, which includes dozens of thousands of possibilities.

Comment: @Bregalad , _Q&A for people interested in governments, policies, and political processes_ This is related to **policies**. As for possibilities, since this isn't targeted Q&A, I believe some answers to questions are incorrect vary by country too.

Comment: @watcher, attacking offices are illegal and I can prosecute them afterwards. Casualties involved are usually the ones who are involved too except few accidents. Even if some people are killed by them, they're targets. However, terrorists are different. They're people who manslaughter innocents, uncontrollable and it's less likely to make them face the laws afterwards, either they escape or commit suicide before arrest causing the innocents to die with no justice. The no. of victims of terrorism will be much bigger than originary riots since they're heavily armed with modern weapons (i.e. guns)

Comment: In addiction, e.g. I offended Christian religion. I should still be able to enter non-Christian countries as per normal unless I'm convicted for that case.

Comment: @XPMai I was attempting to draw a similarity between _killing ISIS member publicly_ and _drawing a cartoon that offends others_. Everyone knew Charlie Hebdo was a potential target for terrorists (mostly because they had _already_ been attacked once before in 2011), yet, as far as I know, there were _zero_ travel restrictions placed on them or their employees.  I guess now I'm a little confused as to what your question is after your comment.

Comment: @watcher, not everyone knows about Charlie Hebdo. I was confused what he did and offended who, but I've understood after your comment. :D

Answer (score 2):

Legally speaking, I have never heard of any laws specifically targeting that but you certainly could be banned on an *ad hoc* basis. Many countries have rules in place to ban certain individuals on ‘public safety’ grounds that could presumably be invoked in this case.

Comment: Also, if they think you might be seeking asylum, they may not let you in unless you go through that process.  I think - I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Bobson The way this works, at least in Europe, is that people who are likely to seek asylum typically need a visa and do not get it, to make sure they don't go as far as being able to lodge an application. But if your citizenship allows you to enter without a visa (which I took for granted for this question) and you make it to the border, you can lodge an application then and there. If you do need a visa, that's another choking point, there are usually multiple legally valid reasons to refuse a visa.

Comment: but the "_ad hoc_" can't be instant, legislations need time right? :D So by the time the government make that legislation, I already legally become a resident.